# Add IP Exception In iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I have a rule to block specific strings incoming to the server. For Ex. 'Abc'
But I want an exception for my Ip Address so that i can sent that to my server
while others can't and their connection drops
My Code Looks Like This:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m string --string "Abc" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j ACCEPT
```

What this does is it stops the people from abusing in my server.
But I want some Exceptions. Lol
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `iptables` the first matching rule wins, therefore right before every `DROP` rule add `ACCEPT` rule, which matches your IP address.